# Track users GPS location in the background and notify if he is next to a certain point

Tags: android, ios, gps, geolocation, push-notification

I have a theoretical question. I want to track a user with my app (iOS and Android) in order to notify him at a given time (11:45am) and **just** if he is next to a specific location (with lat/lng) **even when the app is not open**.

Is it better to check the users location every 5 minutes when the device tracks a 500m change, and make a request to the server (if the time is right, and if the location is right), and then send out a push notification (when location and time is right)? Or should I send out a transparent push notification (without a visual notification) in order to wake up the app and to check the current location of the user? Is this a common practice?

**EDIT** I think the question is not as clear as I thought it will be, so I want to be more precise: I want to notify my user (iOS and Android) if they are at a specific location (specified with lat/lng) at a given time (e.g.: 11:00am), even when the app is closed.

How can I do that?

Comment: for android there is [GeofencingApi](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingApi.html) ... also it seems like you have a problem with see the differences between push notifications and notifications (you can always show a notification without push technology) fx from  BroadcastReciver ... push is for sending small data from the cloud to device and has nothing to do with showing the notification on device

Comment: What is your accuracy requirement measured in meters (related to "next to a certain position") ?

Comment: @AlexWien 500m is ok

Comment: @JohnBrunner have you solved the task? I have similar task and searching around implementation

Answer (score 0):

Your 500m requirement is inbetween GPS and cell tower.

cell tower locationing has about 1000m acuracy in cities and up to 3km in rural regions, this location technique is used in geofencing and the ios auto-wakeup (your "when the app is not open") is used. This does not need much battery.

GPS has about 3-20m, accuracy and uses more battery. battery consumption does not change wheter you check every second, or let the APi call you every 100m. Some highest acuracy mode ios (mode best_for navigation), addionally enable acceleration sensor, whigh might need a bit more power then. (This mode, you dont need)

(In cities also the Wlan location technique may provide a location probbaly meeting your req.)

So you have the choice between 1000m low battery or 5m high battery consumption.
There is nothing inbetween (besides sometimes WLAN).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this doesn't relates to my question, as you describe the general methods of locating a user, but not how I can wake up my app in order to get the location of a user and react to it.